# How can I use VBA to locate a cell within excel based on the contents of that cell and then move that cell (offset) to the right one cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a VBA program that will locate a cell based on a phrase within that cell (ex. "period"). Then cut that cell and move it to the right one cell. I've been using .Cells.Find(what:="period") to locate the cell and then trying to offset it by (0,1). The below is what I have so far but I can't figure out how to cut and paste the cell. Thank you for any help!

```
Sub FP()
    Dim reconCell As Range
    Dim offsetCell As Range
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set reconCell = .Cells.Find(what:="Reconciliation Period")
  
    Set offsetCell = reconCell.Offset(0, 1)
     
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `reconCell.Cut reconCell.Offset(,1)`?

Comment: `reconCell.cut offsetCell `

Comment: It's possible to have only one line in the sub: `With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:="Reconciliation Period"): .Cut .Offset(0, 1): End With`